# Connected But Not Path-Connected?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

Can you think of any spaces that are connected but not path connected apart from the Topologist's Sine Curve?

Comment: I like this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463753/472818

Answer (score 24):

Here are a whole bunch from [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org), a searchable version of Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*. You can visit the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Connected%2B%7EPath%20Connected) to learn more about any of these spaces.

An Altered Long Line

A Pseudo-Arc

Cantor's Leaky Tent

Closed Topologist's Sine Curve

Countable Complement Extension Topology

Countable Complement Topology

Double Pointed Countable Complement Topology

Finite Complement Topology on a Countable Space

Gustin's Sequence Space

Indiscrete Irrational Extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Indiscrete Rational Extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Irrational Slope Topology

Lexicographic Ordering on the Unit Square

Nested Angles

One Point Compactification of the Rationals

Pointed Irrational Extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Pointed Rational Extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Relatively Prime Integer Topology

Roy's Lattice Space

Smirnov's Deleted Sequence Topology

The Extended Long Line

The Infinite Broom

The Infinite Cage

Topologist's Sine Curve

Answer (score 7):

An example of a connected space that is not path-connected is the [deleted comb space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space):
$$ (\{0\} \times \{0,1\}) \cup (K \times [0,1]) \cup ([0,1] \times \{0\})$$
where $K = \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Taken from [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090811084854AAv4lCe).

Answer (score 6):

Another standard example is the [extended long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29). [*Counterexamples in Topology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) will have more, but my copy isn't to hand right now.

Comment: Nice example!___

Answer (score 5):

The canonical example is the [extended long line](http://enwp.org/Long_line). You can think of the regular line $[0,\infty)$ as the product of $[0,1)$ and $\omega$ in the dictionary order topology—effectively, a countable number of copies of $[0, 1)$ pasted end-to-end.

The long line is the same way, except that instead of a countable number of copies you use an uncountable number of copies: take $[0, 1)\times\omega_1$ in the dictionary order topology, where $\omega_1$ is the smallest uncountable ordinal. Then to get the *extended* long line, you add one more point $p$ onto the far end.  It's clearly connected, but it isn't path-connected because the path from any finite point, say $(1/2, 1)$, is too far from $p$ for the path between them to be the image of $[0,1]$.

The book *Counterexamples in Topology* by Seebach and Steen is good for answering questions like this.

Comment: The long line *is* path connected. All locally path connected and connected spaces are path connected.

Comment: @George: The space I described is not locally path-connected in a neighborhood of the extra point $p$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant. Shouldn't this be called the extended long line (or ray)? I don't think the long line has an extra point added at the end.

Comment: @George: That is my fault. I will edit the reply.  Thanks for pointing out that I misspoke.

Comment: Ah, ok, I agree that this is a valid example now.

Comment: @George: Are you sure that the terminology on this does not vary? I know Steen and Seebach call the larger space the "extended" long line, but I remember being surprised when I first saw that, and it seems that Brett Frankel may also have been using the same different terminology that I was. I thought the example appeared in Kelley (1955) but I have only the 1975 edition online, which does not mention it by name.

Comment: No, I'm not sure that the terminology doesn't vary. I did check the wikipedia link though, and they use "long line" to mean without the additional point added.

Comment: I think Wikipedia follows S&S. 1955 Kelley is the same as 1975 Kelley. I wonder if the example is in Munkres?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite example is the [Solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)#Pathological_properties). It is also a topological group, which usually don't admit such weird pathological properties.