# Complement of simple, unbounded curve is not path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, curves, path-connected

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous, injective function that is unbounded on both $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. Is it possible for the complement of the image of the function to be path-connected?

In [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463708/does-the-jordan-curve-theorem-apply-to-non-closed-curves) the answer gives a example for which the complement of the image is connected, but not path-connected. Also, there are suggestions in the comments to extend the range of the function to $S^2$ and apply some form of the Jordan curve theorem, which would give a negative answer to this question, but I'm not sure if such extension can work without requiring stronger properties than just unboundedness.

Comment: An extension of $f$ to a map $F : S^1 \to S^2$ is possible iff $f(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \pm \infty$. However, in general the latter is not true. See the example in your link.